# Java standalone app with dynamic configuration via server over HTTP

Tags: java

i am writing a standalone java app. the app's properties should be configurable from a webpage deployed with the app. how do i achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

note: the app has an embedded HTTP client/server module. it should only run from command prompt

Comment: How do you plan to persist other data for the app?  Database, flat file, etc?

Comment: A standalone application configured via a web page seems to me to be a clash of technologies / ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's a good idea. Webpage forms are designed to work with a server, not with a standalone client app. You could have the app run its own web server, but that would mean the app has to be running for the configuration page to work, and it's also a rather contrived setup just to do some configuration.

It *might* be possible for the webpage to contain JavaScript that writes to a local file - I don't know enough about the JavaScript security model to say.

But why not have the configuration dialog as part of the app's GUI? That's the normal and expected behaviour - you'd need a pretty compelling reason to deviate from it.

Comment: looks like it is a server app.

Answer (score 2):

JMX might be the answer that you're looking for. If you expose all of your configurable properties through MBeans, then adding a web page on top of that exposing these properties is just configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch a standalone Java app using JNLP files (Java WebStart). If you want the user to be able to configure the application before its launched, you can have the JNLP file dynamically generated, then pass properties as environment variables through the JNLP file.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your standalone Java app to read configurable properties from a properties file (say *conf.properties*) on the server.

You may have a UI webpage (html/jsp) with all the field to be configured. When the page is submitted a JSP/Servlet may write/update the contents of *conf.properties* on the server.

**UPDATE:** The above solution will work assuming only an admin user wants to update the properties file.
In case anybody should be able  to update it, then concurrency issue has to be taken into account.

In that scenario, you have to implement a mechanism similar to how weblogic10 updates **config.xml** using [Admin Console](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ConsoleHelp/core/index.html).

i.e. You will have 2 **conf.properties** files **confA** & **confB** (initially in sync). The standalone app will always read from **confB**. The UI will have 2 buttons say Lock & Release configurations. When an edit is made (locked & released), it will be written to **confA** and at the same time changes of confA has to be replicated to **confB**.

Comment: This is an insanely bad idea.

How would this work if you've got a large number of concurrent users?

Comment: @Reverend Gonzo updated the response for your req.
after the UPDATE,  make sense ???